# Difference between array and matrix numpy for solving linear equations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, linear-equation

There are many questions already asked in the same grounds.
I also read the official documentation (http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#what-is-the-difference-between-matrices-and-arrays) regarding the differences. But I am still struggling to understand the philosophical difference between numpy arrays and matrices.

More preciously I am seeking the reason for the below mention results.

```
   #using array
>>> A = np.array([[ 1, -1,  2],
              [ 0,  1, -1],
              [ 0,  0,  1]])
>>> b = np.array([5,-1,3])
>>> x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
>>> x
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])

`#using matrix
>>> A=np.mat(A)
>>> b=np.mat(b)
>>> A
matrix([[ 1, -1,  2],
        [ 0,  1, -1],
        [ 0,  0,  1]])
>>> b
matrix([[ 5, -1,  3]])
>>> x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
>>> x
matrix([[  5.,  -1.,   3.],
        [ 10.,  -2.,   6.],
        [  5.,  -1.,   3.]])
```

Why the linear equations represented as array yields correct solution while the matrix representation yields another matrix solution.

Also honestly I don't understand the reason for getting matrix as a solution in the second case.

Sorry if the question is already answered and I failed to notice and also pardon me if my understanding of numpy array and matrix is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a transpose issue...when you go to matrix land, column-vectors and row-vectors are no longer interchangeable:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[ 1, -1,  2],
              [ 0,  1, -1],
              [ 0,  0,  1]])
b = np.array([5,-1,3])
x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
print 'arrays:' 
print x

A = np.matrix(A)
b = np.matrix(b)
x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
print 'matrix, wrong set up:'
print x

b = b.T
x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
print 'matrix, right set up:'
print x
```

yields:

```
arrays:
[ 1.  2.  3.]
matrix, wrong set up:
[[  5.  -1.   3.]
 [ 10.  -2.   6.]
 [  5.  -1.   3.]]
matrix, right set up:
[[ 1.]
 [ 2.]
 [ 3.]]
```

Comment: Now I realized where I was wrong. Thanks a lot. The answer is perfect perfect to the tee.

Comment: @SaulloCastro Thanks for notifying me. I didn't know that I can accept an answer. I am a newbie to stackoverflow.com.